# Sorting DOM elements with sort() trouble in IE9-10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sorting, dom

I have this code that works perfectly in latest Chrome, Firefox, Opera, but fails in IE9-10:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#wrap'),
    para = document.querySelectorAll('#wrap p');

var paraArr = [].slice.call( para ).sort(function( a,b ) {
  return a.textContent > b.textContent;
});

paraArr.forEach(function( p ) {
  div.appendChild( p );
});
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2nUMk/1/

Any ideas what the problem is? Is the `sort` implementation not the same in IE as in other browsers? Is even `sort` the problem here?

Comment: the `div.innerHTML = '';` is not needed because `appendChild` moves elements but i doubt that that solves the problem, just wanted to note that.

Comment: Right, it didn't, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need in `div.innerHTML = "";` since it removes the sorted elements.

In the sorter function you may explicitly set the returned values:

```
var paraArr = [].slice.call(para).sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.textContent > b.textContent ? 1 : -1;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2nUMk/3/